# Sign up a new account from mobile app to rails devise app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, devise, http-authentication

I am using HTTP authentication to sign_in and sign_out. It works great. However, I want to allow users to sign_up for a new account from my mobile app and then send that over using POST and in JSON format. What do I have to do to make this work?

I am using Devise for authentication for my Rails app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can POST an http-request with your username/password parameters to your login controller action (which could be as simple as requesting `/login?user=foo&pass=bar`), specifying `.json` [format (using respond_to)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds/ClassMethods.html). You may need to include the CSRF, too. And I'm assuming here, since you didn't specify the mobile platform or post any code, that you've got the 'making the actual request' part down.

Comment: Thanks for your help. 1) How would I do that using cURL? 2) I'm new to rails, where do I add the respond_to? I can't seem to find the users controller. Do I have to generate my own users controller?

Comment: Run `rails generate devise:install` and `rails generate devise user` if you haven't already.